# Unable to print updated values in Reactive inputs using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

We have a situation where in we would want to take inputs from user in a datatable by creating dynamic drop-downs and would want to save the data locally. We have tried multiple combinations however these are not getting working in our scenario for e.g.: reset, refresh (can't use it as we have a login page). Below is the reproducible e.g.:

The problem with the code is that it takes old value not the updated one.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Selectinput column in a table',
  h3("Source:", tags$a("Yihui Xie", href = "https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/")),
  numericInput('num', "enter a number", value = 5, min = 1, max = 10, step = 1),
  DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
  verbatimTextOutput('sel'),
  actionButton(
    "saveBtn",
    "Submit Request",
    style = "color: #fff; background-color: #282364;
                                     border-color: #2e6da4",
    class = "btn btn-primary"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    df <- head(iris, input$num)
    
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      df$species_selector[i] <- as.character(selectInput(paste0("sel", i),
                                                         "",
                                                         choices = unique(iris$Species),
                                                         width = "100px"))
    }
    df
  })
  
  output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
    data(), escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
    options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
    callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
        var $this = $(this.node());
        $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
        $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
      });
      Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
      Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
  )
  output$sel = renderPrint({
    str(sapply(1:nrow(data()), function(i) input[[paste0("sel", i)]]))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$saveBtn, {
    
    Test_Data <- sapply(1:nrow(data()), function(i) input[[paste0("sel", i)]])
    Test_Data <- as.data.frame(Test_Data)
    print(Test_Data)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

One solution could be creating dynamic ID's, however this can create complexity in our model as we have multiple drop-downs :
https://community.rstudio.com/t/update-dt-table-dropdowns-with-reactive-data-in-shiny/96100/2

Comment: We are also looking for similar solution from long time. I hope experts can share thier views here

Answer (score 1):

You can execute JavaScript to periodically update selected values of dropdown menus:

e.g. JavaScript e.g. invoked by function `shinyjs::runjs`

```
document.getElementById("sel1").value = "versicolor"
```